# Rails ActiveRecord query ambiguous column name error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have User model and I need to create a query, like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.id FROM users as u
LEFT JOIN lists_users as lu ON lu.user_id = u.id
WHERE u.id != 3
AND lu.list_id != 34
```

I try

```
scope :include_current_user, lambda { |user, list|
 joins('LEFT JOIN lists_users AS lu ON lu.user_id = id')
 .where('id != :user_id AND lu.list_id != :list_id', user_id: user.id, list_id: list.id)
```

}

but I have error

`SQLite3::SQLException: ambiguous column name: id: SELECT "users".* FROM "users" LEFT JOIN lists_users AS lu ON lu.user_id = id WHERE (id != 2 AND lu.list_id != 34)`

How to create this with the help of an ActiveRecord query ?

Comment: Don't you need to specify `users.id` to avoid the ambiguity?

Comment: I need inlude specific user id in this sql example I exclude user id = 3 and exclude lu.list_id for table lists_users, this table have alias lu

Comment: How to active record created query like in example

Comment: You can specify `id` field from user table: `scope :include_current_user, lambda { |user, list|
 joins('LEFT JOIN lists_users AS lu ON lu.user_id = users.id')
 .where('users.id != :user_id AND lu.list_id != :list_id', user_id: user.id, list_id: list.id)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Rails 5, you can use `left_outer_joins` for the query, and also you can use `not` to negate the conditions of where, also to prevent ambiguous column you can put in the conditions the table name so you will finish with a query like

```
left_outer_joins(:list_users).where.not(users: { id: user.id }, list_users: { list_id: list.id })
```

Comment: result this query have many user with one id, need use ditinct ot group by. How do this?

Comment: @shuba.ivan just include `.distinct` to the query

Comment: what ide you use? In ruby mine when put crtl + space not see possible function, not see function for query, maybe need some plugin, but I can't find plugin